# Pivoting a table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a TVF that returns two columns: 'measure' (a name) and 'score', a numeric score for that measure:

```
dbo.ScoringFunction(param1, param2, ..., paramN)
Measure   Score
-------   -----
measure1  10
measure2  5
...       ...
measureN  15
```

I'm running this function against a large number of rows that contain its parameters:

```
Name   Param1   Param2   ...   ParamN
----   ------   ------         ------
Daniel 12       5              6
etc.
```

I am trying to find a way to display the measures and their scores next to the parameters that determine those scores:

```
Name   Param1   Param2   ...   ParamN   measure1   measure2   ...   measureN
----   ------   ------         ------   --------   --------         --------
Daniel 12       5              6        10         5                15
etc.
```

So far I have tried using a pivot table, but it's tricky since the data being pivoted is contained in a TVF rather than a static table. I've also tried using CROSS APPLY, but once I have the data (measures & scores), I'm still unable to pivot it into a nicely formatted row.

If anybody has any ideas, they would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the TVF get its data? Maybe you could show us the source data, a few rows of sample data, and desired results. It's quite possible that the TVF is an unnecessary hurdle, but there aren't enough details here for anyone to say for sure.

Comment: So you call `dbo.ScoringFunction` with a bunch of INT values? So from the second record set, you take the param columns and send their values into the function and get some rows out that you want to pivot? How many measure rows come out? `PIVOT` can't make a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore It's around 15 or so measures (don't remember offhand, but it's a fixed number, and they have fixed names).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can't share the source data, but I can try to explain what the TVF is doing. The TVF produces a table by union-ing together a number of individual queries of the form "SELECT measure, score WHERE value IS BETWEEN low_number and high_number AND measure = 'whatever'", so it ends up with the schema of the first snippet (measure, score). The table the TVF is querying is a scoring rubric: it consists of a number of measures along with ranges of values for each measure and scores for each range (i.e. there is no algorithm that could produce these values). Does that help?

Comment: Not really, can you make up something simple and post it to http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a47b/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing too much (hopefully), I would do the pivoting *in the function*, then use the function in CROSS APPLY and pull the columns. So if your function is something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ScoringFunction (parameters)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (

SELECT Measure, Score
FROM …

)
```

then I would rewrite it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ScoringFunction (parameters)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (

WITH originalSelect AS (
  SELECT Measure, Score
  FROM …
)
SELECT
  measure1,
  measure2,
  …
FROM originalSelect
PIVOT (
  MAX(Score) FOR Measure IN (measure1, measure2, …)
) p

)
```

and use it in the final query like this:

```
SELECT
  t.Name,
  t.param1,
  t.param2,
  …
  x.measure1,
  x.measure2,
  …
FROM atable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ScoringFunction (t.param1, t.param2, …) x
```

Comment: In your final query you can just do `... FROM atable t CROSS APPLY dbo.ScoringFunction(t.param1, t.param2, ...)`. There is no need to put it in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a function that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetSpecificMeasures]
(
    @HeightScore INT
    , @WeightScore INT
    , @TvScore INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(
    SELECT
        Final.Height AS tv_height_score
        , Final.[Weight] AS tv_weight_score
        , Final.TV AS tv_score
    FROM
    (
        SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'Height' AND @HeightScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
            UNION ALL
        SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'Weight' AND @WeightScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
            UNION ALL
        SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'TV' AND @TvScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
    ) Base
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(score) 
        FOR measure
        IN
        (
            [Height]
            , [Weight]
            , [TV]
        )
    ) Final
);
GO
```

And one that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetMeasureScore]
(
    @Measure VARCHAR(50)
    , @Value INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(
    SELECT
        score
    FROM ScoringRubric
    WHERE measure = @Measure
        AND @Value BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
);
GO
```

Then you can get your data with either of the following:

```
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(50) = 'Daniel'

SELECT
    UserProfile.*
    , HeightScore.score AS tv_height_score
    , WeightScore.score AS tv_weight_score
    , TvScore.score AS tv_score
FROM UserProfile
INNER JOIN ScoringRubric HeightScore
    ON HeightScore.measure = 'Height'
    AND UserProfile.height BETWEEN HeightScore.bottom_of_range AND HeightScore.top_of_range
INNER JOIN ScoringRubric WeightScore
    ON WeightScore.measure = 'Weight'
    AND UserProfile.[weight] BETWEEN WeightScore.bottom_of_range AND WeightScore.top_of_range
INNER JOIN ScoringRubric TvScore
    ON TvScore.measure = 'TV'
    AND UserProfile.TV BETWEEN TvScore.bottom_of_range AND TvScore.top_of_range
WHERE UserProfile.name = @User

SELECT
    *
FROM UserProfile
CROSS APPLY dbo.fGetSpecificMeasures(height, [weight], TV)
WHERE name = @User

SELECT
    UP.*
    , HeightScore.score AS tv_height_score
    , WeightScore.score AS tv_weight_score
    , TvScore.score AS tv_score
FROM UserProfile UP
CROSS APPLY fGetMeasureScore('Height', UP.height) HeightScore
CROSS APPLY fGetMeasureScore('Weight', UP.[weight]) WeightScore
CROSS APPLY fGetMeasureScore('TV', UP.TV) TvScore
WHERE UP.name = @User
```

I don't really know which one you'll find most appropriate for your uses. Let me know if you have questions.

As for your original question, if this were the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetMeasureScoresOriginal]
(
    @HeightScore INT
    , @WeightScore INT
    , @TvScore INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
(
    SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'Height' AND @HeightScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
        UNION ALL
    SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'Weight' AND @WeightScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
        UNION ALL
    SELECT measure, score FROM ScoringRubric WHERE measure = 'TV' AND @TvScore BETWEEN bottom_of_range AND top_of_range
)
GO
```

Then you could write the query and pivot like so:

```
SELECT
    Final.name
    , Final.OriginalHeight AS height
    , Final.OriginalWeight AS [weight]
    , Final.OriginalTv AS TV
    , Final.Height AS tv_height_score
    , Final.[Weight] AS tv_weight_score
    , Final.TV AS tv_score
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UP.name
        , UP.height AS OriginalHeight
        , UP.[weight] AS OriginalWeight
        , UP.TV AS OriginalTv
        , Measures.measure
        , Measures.score
    FROM UserProfile UP
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fGetMeasureScoresOriginal(UP.height, UP.[weight], UP.TV) Measures
    WHERE UP.name = @User
) Base
PIVOT
(
    MAX(score)
    FOR measure
    IN
    (
        [Height]
        , [Weight]
        , [TV]
    )
) Final
```

**EDIT**: Just realized I didn't answer the original question. Adding that now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pivot a static set of rows you can use the  technique as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704428/how-to-write-a-query-using-self-join-on-a-table-with-huge-data/10737836#10737836).

Reposting the example, so it will be different tables, but the technique can be applied in your case as well I think.

```
SELECT
  Customers.CustID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CF.FieldID = 1 THEN CF.FieldValue ELSE NULL END) AS Field1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CF.FieldID = 2 THEN CF.FieldValue ELSE NULL END) AS Field2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CF.FieldID = 3 THEN CF.FieldValue ELSE NULL END) AS Field3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CF.FieldID = 4 THEN CF.FieldValue ELSE NULL END) AS Field4
  -- Add more...

  FROM Customers 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomFields CF
  ON CF.ID = Customers.CustID

  WHERE Customers.CustName like 'C%'

  GROUP BY Customers.CustID
```